# Wordpress print all inline styles to head

Tags: php, html, wordpress, function

Currently working on a project here http://palanquin.shrimp-works.com. When I try to validate what I have done so far, using http://validator.w3.org/, I get lots of this error **Element style not allowed as child of element div in this context.** (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.), which basically means there is a div which is printing it's styles to the body tag of my document. This is invalid. Simple styles like background color, text color, etc are all being printed in the body tag of the html, ruining any chance of html5 validation.

Is there a wordpress filter that can print all **style tags** in the wordpress text editor or tinymce to the head instead of to the body? I know how to enqueue inline styles in functions.php. I don't think that's what I need here. Any ideas?

Comment: I would rather worry about that ridiculous amount of requests, size and speed of that site.

Comment: @PeeHaa I'll worry about that. I'm worried about ^^^this now!

Comment: I don't think validating Wordpress is a viable path. But welcome to SO! As for this question, this might be better suited in wp forums